# Django Attribute Error: "AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'ManytoManyField' "

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am executing this line of code in my terminal:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I get this as output:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Bryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Bryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Bryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Bryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Bryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Bryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Bryan\Desktop\wisdompets\adoptions\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Pet(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Bryan\Desktop\wisdompets\adoptions\models.py", line 13, in Pet
    vaccinations = models.ManytoManyField('Vaccine', blank=True)
**AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'ManytoManyField'**
```

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `To` in `ManyToManyField` is with a capital.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to do more reading of the documentation before I begin implementing a project using Django

Answer (score 0):

The t needs to be capitalized in the ManyToManyField portion, Also Vaccine should reference a model

if it's in a different models.py.

from [Appname].models import Vaccine

vaccinations = models.ManyToManyField(Vaccine, blank=True).